# unable to view next page when i use grid view

Tags: asp.net, mysql, gridview

Am new to asp.net. I am using grid view to display my data from the databasE(MySQL).

**Code for grid view:**

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="gvCity" runat="server" AllowPaging="True">
</asp:GridView>
</form>
```

AllowPaging will only me to view the data in pages. Basically, when I click on the second page, it gives out an error.

**Error message:**

The GridView 'gvCity' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The GridView 'gvCity' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `gridview` data again in `PageIndexChanging` event & Set `PageIndex`

```
Protected Sub GridViewName_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridViewName.PageIndexChanging
  GridViewName.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
  GridViewName.DataSource = DataSourceForGridView
  GridViewName.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: anyway, thanks for the codes. it helps. however the codes above are for vbscript and i am using c#. but i editeed it and it works now. (:

Answer (score 0):

You have specified that you allow pagination but you are not handling the pagination event "PageIndexChanging", I take it that the gridview isn't databound which forces you to handle everything yourself.